# Is indexOf() type sensitive in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function that iterates each object in an array to get their id and then filtering the result using a given id:

```
const id = another.id; //variable used to filter through the items
const pos = this.items.map(function(e){return e.id}).indexOf(id); //filter items with another.id
this.items.splice(pos, 1) //remove item with the same id as another.id
```

The `another.id` would sometimes be a `string` and sometimes be a `number`, it would work when the type is `string` but `pos` would become `-1` indicating that `indexOf()` didn't find a match. The `e.id`'s are also a typeof `string`.

So my question would be as the title says, is `indexOf()` type sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's type sensitive according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

Comment: is there an alternative to `indexOf()` that is not type sensitive? That would use `==` as comparator instead of `===`?

Comment: @YongPin `this.items.findIndex(e => e.id == id)`